# Can we describe the connected components in the graph of $\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x+y\right)=\cos\left(x^{2}y\right)$?

Tags: graphing-functions, connectedness, path-connected

The graph of $\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x+y\right)=\cos\left(x^{2}y\right)$ is, perhaps unsurprisingly, pretty wild.  [Here is a Desmos version of it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8myabmiurk); a few screenshots are below, showing different scales of the graph.  As can be seen, for small values of $x$ (say $-1.5 \le x \le 1.5$) the graph consists of individual simple closed loops; this pattern persists as you move up and down the $y$-axis, although the loops become smaller and more squished together.

[image]

However, for larger values of $x$, the loops merge together into what appears to be a single enormous zig-zag pattern.  What appear in this image to be isolated points are actually an artifact of Desmos's inability to resolve the fine details; zooming in more closely reveals that they are actually connected.  This raises the provocative question:  how much of this function is actually connected?

[image]

My question is:  are there any techniques that can be used to describe the connected components of this wild graph?  For example, if everything with $x > 5$ path-connected?

Comment: Beautiful graph :-).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a plot in *Mathematica* `ContourPlots` with high resolution:

[image]

While each contour will be continuous (i.e., no isolated points as we see in the OP's plot), there may indeed be unconnected contour segments.

Comment: The solution set to an equation $F(x,y)=0$ need not be connected even if $F(x,y)$ is continuous. So continuity is insufficient to deduce connectedness.

Comment: For example the solution set to $xy=1$ is disconnected.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip That's exactly the example I was about to provide:  the graph of $xy = 1$ has two connected components. Continuity and connectedness are two different things!  And the graph I asked about is *clearly* disconnected near the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks for providing a neater graphical representation but "easy to see" is not the same a mathematical proof.